# Downloading files from service (with updating UI)

Tags: android, service, download

I have a tricky use case that I'm trying to find best design for. The description is:

- there should be a `FolderListActivity` with corresponding view, which shows a list of folders available for download

  - user is able to long-press on item, and add it to download queue
- another activity called `DownloadingQueueActivity` should be available, which:

  - shows list of items on queue, with progress bar (downloaded files / total files)
  - it's rearrangeable (user should be able to change the order of items on queue)
  - item can be deleted (or even whole queue)
  - downloading can be paused

Furthermore, this should be handled by service, because downloads should be continued after quitting from application. As such, a service should be able to:

- download files in folders from queue
- notify `DownloadingQueueActivity` on progress
- listen on queue's changes (caused by `DownloadingQueueActivity`)

I tried doing this through [`Messenger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html), but I ended up with lots of different types of messages, which I don't find as elegant solution.

Any advice or even hint on implementing this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right track.  You will have your DownloadService which is processing all of the downloads.  Your `DownloadingQueueActivity` can bind to this [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).  When it binds, you can then get all of the necessary information to update the activity.

As for the push notifications, you can use a listener.  So create a new Interface for the Activiy to implement:

```
public static interface DownloadListener {

    void updateViews(int progress);
}
```

Then add this function to your Activity.

```
public class DownloadingQueueActivity {

    public void updateViews(int progress) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update views
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then add the listener to the service after it binds:

```
private ServiceConnection listenerStarter = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        DownloadService ds = ((DownloadService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        ds.addListener(DownloadingQueueActivity.this);

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    }

};
```

Then in your DownloadService, when it's time to update the views, just send a message to the listener that has been set in the service (also dont forget to create the addListener function in the service as well as removing the listener in the onStop() of the Activity):

```
listener.updateViews(30);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I've got two questions:
- how would you implement the downloading part? my only concern is how to handle queue in service?
- why does updateView run in main thread, even though you are calling it from background thread?

Comment: Figured out answers to my questions. Thanks.

Comment: The updateView thread will not be called on the main UI thread therefore will not allow you to update views.  To fix this you can use the runOnUIThread function. I have updated my example to show this